# How to model two D flip-flops with multiplexing logic

Tags: vhdl

I would like to model two D flip-flops using a multiplexer for some logic. I want to have static outputs of "000" for the three MSB when the multiplexer selects DFF D1 (B = 0) and the three LSB should be fixed to "111" when the multiplexer selects DFF D2 (B = 1).

This is my code -- which I originally typed blindly without checking for obvious syntax errors -- below. I don't know how to solve my problem:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity dff_mux is
Port ( D1, D2 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
      clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
      rst : IN STD_LOGIC;
      B : in  STD_LOGIC;
  data  : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0));
end dff_mux;

architecture Behavioral of dff_mux is

signal Q1, Q2 : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);

begin

process(clk,rst)
begin
    if (rst = '1') then

        Q1<="000000000000";

    elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then

        if (B = '0') then

            -- I want to fix thee MSB to "000"
            -- other bits shall retain their input value
            D1(11) <= '0';
            D1(10) <= '0';
            D1(9) <= '0';
            Q1 <= D1;

        elsif (B = '1') then

            -- fix three LSB to "111"
            -- other bits retain their input value
            D2(2) <= '1';
            D2(1) <= '1';
            D2(0) <= '1';
            Q2 <= D2;

        end if;

    end if;

end process;

-- MUX description: select D1 when B = 0, else select D2 when B = 1

MUX : process(B)
begin

    data <= Q1 when (B = '0') else
            Q2;

end process MUX;

end Behavioral;
```

Thanks in advance to anybody who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous errors in your VHDL design description.  The two process statements drive the same signals (`Q1` and `Q2`).  The second process has three errors (no process statement label, while a label is specified in closing, concurrent signal assignment statements where sequential signal assignment statements are appropriate).  It would appear the second process statement should be eliminated in it's entirety.

If the intent is to have a multiplexer on the inputs to the `Q1`,`Q2` registers the first process is non-functional.  You can't assign values to a formal input inside a block.

You should be assigning the `B` selected values to `Q1` and `Q2` directly inside the process statement (inside the `clk` `elsif`).

Your assignment to D(11) is defective (uses `==` instead of `<=`).

It isn't a multiplexer if you only assign one value to a particular signal (e.g. longest static prefix `D1` and `D2`).  Note there is no reset value for `Q2` provided.

There is no place data is assigned.

If you're doing this for class work there is little benefit in someone providing the answer without learning VHDL a bit more.  If you're earnestly trying to learn VHDL you need more and incrementally building exercises.

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly it would look something like this:

```
architecture Behavioral of basculeD is
-- signal Q1, Q2 : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
begin

-- process(clk,rst)
-- begin
-- if (rst='1') then Q1<="000000000000";
-- elsif ( clk'event and clk='1') then
-- if (B='0') then 
-- D1(11) =='0'; -- i want to fix the 3MSB of D1 in the "000" ... 
-- D1(10) <='0';
-- D1(9) <='0';
-- Q1<= D1;
-- elsif  (B='1') then 
-- D2(2)<= '1'; -- the 3LSB are fixed to 111 , and defaut value ... 
-- D2(1)<='1';
-- D2(0)<='1';
-- Q2<=D2;
-- end if; 
-- end if;
-- end process;

-- description MUX : select D1 when B=0, else select D2 when B= 1  
-- process( B)
-- begin
-- Q1 <= D1 when B='0' else 
-- Q2<=D2 when B='1'  ;
-- end process MUX;

MUXED_REG:
    process (clk,rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then 
            data <= (others => '0'); -- equivalent to "000000000000"
        elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
        -- the actual multiplexer:
            if B = '0' then
                data <= ("000" & D1(8 downto 0));
            else  -- B = '1', or other values
                data <= (D2(11 downto 3) & "111");
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

You could of course retain an intermediary signal, say `Q` and use it in place of data above, with a concurrent signal assignment from `Q` to `data` (the output).

Using the above architecture in place of your's analyzes.

With a test bench:

```
library ieee; 
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity basculeD_test is
end entity;

architecture test of basculeD_test is
    component basculeD is
        port ( 
            d1, d2:  in   std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
            clk:     in   std_logic;
            rst:     in   std_logic;
            b:       in   std_logic;
            data:    out  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    signal d1:      std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal d2:      std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal rst:     std_logic := '1';
    signal b:       std_logic := '0';
    signal data:    std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);

begin

CLOCK: 
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 100 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

RESET:
    process
    begin
        wait for 31 ns;
        rst <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;

DUT:
    basculeD 
        port map (
            d1   => d1,
            d2   => d2,
            clk  => clk,
            rst  => rst,
            b    => b,
            data => data
        );

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 65 ns;
        b <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

And using the replacement architecture for basculeD with the `MUXED_REG` process:

> david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -a basculeD.vhdl
>   david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -e basculeD_test
>   david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -r basculeD_test --wave=basculeD_test.ghw
>   david_koontz@Macbook: open basculeD_test.gtkw  (previously saved save file)

Gives:

[image: Test bench execution of basculeD_test]

There's of course the possibility that you are trying to separate storage from multiplexing entirely, which says you could use `Q1` and `Q2` as registers (and only need 9 bits), a separate multiplexer (as implied in your original `basculeD` `architecture`) allowing `B` to steer between modified `Q1` and `Q2` register values on output `data`.

That would look something like this:

```
architecture Behavioral of basculeD is
    signal Q1:  std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
    signal Q2:  std_logic_vector(11 downto 3);
begin
REGS:
process (clk, rst)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        Q1 <= (others => '0');
        Q2 <= (others => '0');    
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
        Q1 <= D1 (8 downto 0); 
        Q2 <= D2(11 downto 3);
    end if;
end process;

MUX:
process (B,Q1,Q2)
begin
    if B = '0' then
        data <= ("000" & Q1);
    else
        data <= (Q2 & "111");
    end if;
end process;
```

And give you something like this:

[image: basculeD_test with separate MUX]

VHDL is meant to convey a design specification to the reader, which is made easier when using some convention for capitalization (VHDL isn't case sensitive except in extended identifiers) and indentation.

Comment: Just a quick note: when and select statements were added as sequential statements in VHDL 2008. The rest of your answer is great!

Comment: @FRob - Yes, conditional waveforms and selected signal assignments have been added to sequential signal assignment statements in -2008. Do let us know when 1076-2008 is universally supported, particularly for synthesis.

Comment: Synplify can do it, so should Quartus. Xilinx will probably wait till VHDL-2026 tho ;)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! First off, this is an English Question & Answer site. Please translate *all* pertinent terms into English, i.e. basculeD => D flip-flop etc. Also, try to describe your problem the best you can without too many spelling mistakes (spell check!) or grammar errors. This will help other people understand you and help you efficiently.

Anyway, your main problem is, that you have input ports D1 and D2 and you try to write to them. Instead, you should just take whatever bits you need and disregard the other bits.

Instead of trying to write to the input, which is not possible, you should try this:

```
Q2 <= D2(11 downto 3) & "111";
```

This statement takes bits 11 through 3 from D2 and assigns them to bits 11 through 3 of Q2. Bits 2 through 0 of Q2 are assigned a constant value of "111".

You should remember that you cannot "re-write" input port values. Your last process could also be re-written to a parallel statement.

Also, your design is peculiar in the sense that you want to store the modified value separately.

Consider this:

D1 = x"00A"; D2 = x"00B", B = '0', clk --> rising edge

Now, Q1 = x"00A", Q2 = x"???", data = Q1 = x"00A", B = '0', clk = '1'

Now, Q1 = x"00A", Q2 = x"???", data = Q2 = x"???", B = '1', clk = '1'

You need at least two clock periods to switch your outputs when you want to switch between B = '1' and B = '0', because Q1 resp Q2 will hold old (and possibly uninitialized) values.

Your design might not do what you want it to do. If you want a multiplexer, go for a multiplexer. If you want a flip flop, build a flip flop.

```
process(clk,rst)
begin

    if (rst = '1') then

        data <= (others => '0');

    elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then

        if (B = '1') then

            -- Select D2
            data <= D2(11 downto 3) & "111";

        else

            -- Select D1
            data <= "000" & D1(8 downto 0);

        end if;

    end if;

end process;
```

You might also want to think about whether a reset is really appropriate and whether a synchronous reset might be more beneficial.

Comment: thank yo the next time i will  descibe my problem the best as i can , thank you for your precious  help